# Can I see the contents of SAM file with a plain text-editor?

Tags: windows, password-management

I have exported the SAM and SYSTEM as Registry Hive Files and I was wondering         if it is possible to look inside those files to see what they contain? I opened  them with Notepad but I didn't see anything meaningful (to my eyes at least). So I used ophcrack to load the local SAM with samdump2 and I was able to get the NT Hash. I want to know if the SAM file can be read in any other way especially with text editors. Or maybe I should be asking how does samdump2 work?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course open every file in a plain text editor ;)
 The question is if you can get any useful from it. This relies on whether it is a plaintext file or a specific format and also on the encoding used. ***I think in this case it's illegible because of the format*** not the encoding.

Generally there are some ways how tools like samdump2 work. One is to ***access the file with SYSTEM privileges*** (which I think does not work anymore in more modern systems) the other is to ***load some filesystem drivers that simply ignore the assigned privileges***. This is how [`pwdump7`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwdump) works for example. This of course requires administrative rights.

Comment: Does Microsoft provide any information related to the issue at hand?

Comment: About which isse exactly?

Comment: Accessing the source of the file?

Comment: I have not read such but you can find some in the developer notes of pwdump7

Comment: Will look at it.